# When to set related objects with clear=True in Django?

Tags: python, django

The other day I came across the following snippet in the code base I'm working with:

```
instance.teachers.clear()
instance.teachers.add(*teachers)
```

I was wondering how it was different from simply calling `instance.teachers.set(teachers)`.

I [looked `.set()` up in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/relations/#django.db.models.fields.related.RelatedManager.set) which says:

> This method accepts a `clear` argument to control how to perform the
> operation. If `False` (the default), the elements missing from the new
> set are removed using `remove()` and only the new ones are added. If
> `clear=True`, the `clear()` method is called instead and the whole set
> is added at once.

Honestly it's still not clear to me what the difference effectively is. I also checked the [implementation of `.set()`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/0b655a4bf81f640d3e664f398e635943d4fb7812/django/db/models/fields/related_descriptors.py#L988) and co and what I found that calling `clear()`, for instance, will dispatch certain signals. Unless I need this, is there any other point in using it?

Comment: as you mentioned, the only advantage is the ***signals*** emission during the execution of `remove(...)` method

Comment: @ArakkalAbu thanks. would you mind submitting it as an answer? btw can you point to any pages that mentions this? i tried to find more about this but the official docs was very tight-lipped on this